# Parse InDesign (.indd) files for search index

Tags: indexing, solr, text-extraction, adobe-indesign

Could any of you help me with the following:

I have quite a bunch load of InDesign Documents, and I need to be able to search through them, text wise. I don't have the resources of opening these files, make a pdf, and then do the search. I want, in short, to be able to either extract the textual context and index that, or directly index the file itself.

In the end, I would present the content or the index to a SOLR engine for further processing. This all should take place in a php/apache/mysql environment.

Your insights are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to search the textual contents of an InDesign file, you will have to open the file in  InDesign or InDesign server. There is no legal way around this.

However, there is no need to do a time consuming pdf export. You can use the InDesign scripting API to search through the text content of the file and create an index either inside the document or in an external location.

Comment: Thanks. Your statement "There is no legal way around this" is strong enough to make this a credible answer. Are you working with Adobe?

Comment: Not for Adobe directly, but for a partner that creates workflow solutions or small plugins/scripts for doing things like this.

Comment: After [Reading the EULA](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/Gen_WWCombined-MULTI-20111031_1230.pdf) I can find no restriction prohibiting users from parsing InDesign files directly. Could you cite the document you are referring to?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. It could fall under the "reverse engineering" section, or it could be part of the partner program requirements (without access to and extensive knowledge of the SDK you have little to no chance of properly parsing the .indd file anyway).

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for an application that can read & allow you to edit text in InDesign without having to actually have InDesign?

If so, I may be wrong, but there is a product in the market called PageZephyr, from Markzware.

You should look into it, I believe there's  30-day free demo as well. I used it awhile ago and it worked great, saved me tons of time. I don't have much InDesign files nowadays though.

Google them.